# How to get google reader subscription logos

Tags: c#, http, subscription

Am developing apps in `C#` that require access to `Google reader`. I am using the **unofficial Google Reader OAth API**. Thanks to lots of ideas from people like Martin Doms, I am able to do lots of stuff in code for Google Reader.

There is a way to get a list of all subscriptions from Google reader but this list by using the following URL "http://www.google.com/reader/api/0/unread-count?allcomments=true&output=xml&ck=1255643091105&client=scroll". The result (whether in `XML` or `JSON`) doesn't contain links to thumbnails / images representing the logo of the news source. Say I subscribe to Engadget, Al Jazeera and CNET, I would like to get access to the Engadget, Al Jazeera and CNET logos in code. Any ideas how I can do that?

Comment: And your question is?? More important part, did you tried anything? Please read [faq] and [ask]

Comment: How do I get the logos of Google reader subscriptions (news sources)?